# How to open Google Assistant from lock screen without voice command?

Tags: samsung, google, google-assistant

On a Samsung phone, I cant find a way to open/command Google Assistant from lock screen with a touch button or even side keys. Looks like only way to open it from lock screen is "ok google" voice command. I'd like to start it via touch button or side key, not voice. Thanks.

Comment: What model, doe sit have Bixby ?

Comment: @RohitGupta , a52 a32 applies to all models with android 11 i guess.  It has bixby. Having problem with g.asistant though.

Answer (score 0):

### On Android 13

- Open **Settings**
- In Search, type in **Side**
- Click on **Side key**
- Enable **Double Press**
- Select **Open App**
- Select **Google**

Now a double press will launch it.  On my Note 20, it is the **Power** Key.

### On Android 11

I cant test it, but this is supposed to work. You need to make a quick command, change Bixby to double press and assign Google to single press.

- Open Bixby
- Press on three dot menu
- Select **Quick commands**
- Press the **+** button on the upper right of the screen within the **Quick commands** page
- Enter **Google** in the field under "What Bixby does"
- Press **Type a command**
- Enter **Launch Assistant**  exactly
- Press Bixby key once
- In **Settings**
- Enable **Double Press to Open Bixby**  Now Bixby will launch with double press
- Select **Use single press**
- Enable it
- Select **Run quick command**
- Select **Google**

Now Google should open with one click of the Bixby button.
Ref [gadgethacks](https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/easiest-way-make-bixby-button-open-google-assistant-your-galaxy-0194365/)

Comment: Thanks but it didnt work. It only opens after unlocking device besides Google app opens not assistant.

Comment: I think thats the closest you are going to get.  The Google window has the Assistant at the very top.  Its one step closer.